# Stay on same page after sending parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page that i load into a div. the page i load in the div has a link that carries a parameter to a different page for deletion. When i click on the loaded page in the div, it takes me to the deletion page. But what i want it to do is to stay on the page whiles the deletion works.

```
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false }); // This part addresses an IE bug. without it, IE will only load the first number and will never refresh
    setInterval(function() {
    $('#call_fav').load('call_fav.asp');
    }, 3000); // the "3000" here refers to the time to refresh the div. it is in milliseconds.
    });

    // ]]></script>
```

here's the page i call into the div

```
<div class="show-image" id="container">
    <img src="usr_up_img/<%=(rs_favorites.Fields.Item("pic").Value)%>" alt="" height="60" align="left" />
    <input name="fav_id" type="hidden" id="fav_id" value="<%=(rs_favorites.Fields.Item("fav_id").Value)%>" />
    <a href="call_fav.asp?<%= Server.HTMLEncode(MM_keepURL) & MM_joinChar(MM_keepURL) & "fav_id=" & rs_favorites.Fields.Item("fav_id").Value %>">
        <img src="imgs/close.png" alt="" width="15" height="15" class="the-buttons" border="0"/>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Is that all the relevant code? There isn't anything there which should cause you to navigate to a new page

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will have to do this using an iFrame instead of just a div.